# Uneven geometry on semisharp edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, sculpting, geometry

How can I smooth out these harsh edges(circled in red) and make the geometry look more like what I have circled in green.[image: Example Skull]

I've tried using the smooth tool in sculpt mode, and while that does seem to fix the problem, it also ruins the overall shape of the edge by rounding it off.
Do I have to retopologize this mesh altogether or is it saveable?

Comment: Hi, please add the blend file to the question so we can take a closer look. You can use: [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Although retopology would be the best/most logical solution here, you could try to use the `pinch tool`, which pinches/squeezes geometry, and hold  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  to do the reverse (spread out/smooths the geometry out). A subdivision modifier here would be impractical since your mesh is already pretty dense as shown in the image you've provided.

If the pinch too doesn't, I suggest you go straight to retopology. It's good practice to do so.